# Ubuntu Server 18.04 SSD cache on software RAID

Tags: server, 18.04, raid, lvm, bcache

I have an installation consisting of 2 HDDs and 1 SSD. I want to run the 2 HDD's in a software RAID 1 with the SSD caching the array. Has somebody done this on Ubuntu Server 18.04 and if so, what were the steps involved?

Thank you.

If it helps, I have a UEFI system.

Comment: SD is a Secure Digital card. I hope you mean a Solid state drive (ssd).

Comment: Yep, my apologies, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I've done RAID5 on top of Bcache.

With Bcache you format a backing device (eg. HDD) and a SSD cache with make-bcache. The backing device will show up as /dev/bcacheX and is then treated as a regular block device you add to your array.

If you format the cache and backing device the same time the SSD will automatically be added as the cache. If you do them separately you need to attach the bcache0 device to the cache via the /sysfs interface.

One cache (SSD cache partition) can serve multiple backing devices (eg. HDD).

The there's a page on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/Bcache) with Ubuntu specific steps and also read the [kernel docs page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/bcache.html).

Note that there's been a performance regression in bcache related to read ahead I/O that's fixed in very recent kernels (after 10th of February 2020), so for some workloads it'll perform much better in 20.04 (or if trying out the latest kernels).